# How to exit command if command does not output anything for 10 seconds?

Tags: shell

I want to ssh IP obtained in varible "a". this works fine if everything is ok.
But if my command "commandToGetIP" get stuck in network or by any chance it will not return any output my script will go in hung state. 
Now what i need to get is this command "commandToGetIP" should wait only for 10 sec and come out giving some message

a=`commandToGetIP  <DeviceID>`
ssh $a

I want to ssh IP obtained in varible "a". this works fine if everything is ok.
But if my command "commandToGetIP" get stuck in network or by any chance it will not return any output my script will go in hung state. 
Now what i need to get is this command "commandToGetIP" should wait only for 10 sec and come out giving some message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, bash has a built in command to timeout another command. If the command takes too long, timeout will kill it with exit code 143. Using this information, I am checking to see if the exit code was *not* 143 before performing the ssh command. Otherwise, it'll do whatever you want it to do when commandToGetIP takes too long.

```
timeout 10 commandToGetIP <DeviceID> | read ip
result=$?
if [ "$result" != "143" ]; then
    ssh $ip
else
    # What we do if it times out
fi
```

Comment: Thanks For grt answer

Comment: The number 10 right after `timeout...` indicates the number of seconds it will wait. So here, it is 10 seconds.